# getTaskFieldAsync truncates fieldValue with newline for notes field

Tags: office-js, officedev

I am creating a Project add-in that reads tasks - i am specifically interested in reading the notes field (Office.ProjectTaskFields.Notes)

I have a working code that enumerates all tasks and notes in each of them, using the getTaskFieldAsync method.

However, if the notes field contain multiline text, i only receive back the first line with trailing 3 dots ...

Is there anyway to resolve this and get the full content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are seeing is the current design. The property will only ever return the first line. There is no way to get at the multiple lines.

Chris